# Viewing model coefficients for a single prediction

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I have a logistic regression model housed in a scikit-learn pipeline using the following:

```py
pipeline = make_pipeline(
    StandardScaler(),
    LogisticRegressionCV(
        solver='lbfgs',
        cv=10,
        scoring='roc_auc',
        class_weight='balanced'
    )
)

pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = pipeline.predict(X_test)
```

I can view the model's coefficients for predictions as a whole with this code ...

```py
# Look at model's coefficients to see what features are most important
plt.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 50
model = pipeline.named_steps['logisticregressioncv']
coefficients = pd.Series(model.coef_[0], X_train.columns)
plt.figure(figsize=(10,12))
coefficients.sort_values().plot.barh(color='grey');
```

Which returns a bar plot of the features and their coefficients.

What I'm *trying* to do is be able to see how different input values for a single observation impact its prediction. The idea is to be able to run predictions on a sample population and examine the group with "low" predictions ... for example if I run predictions for 10 observations, I'd like to see how different input values impacted each of those 10 predictions, individually.

Comment: @desertnaut Hence the "I'm not entirely sure if this is possible and this may be exposing a misunderstanding of how these coefficients are generated / what they represent" ... thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Respectfully declining, as I think it's certainly possible others could have confusion on this topic and benefit from seeing the explanation/clarification provided

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Recalled that I can achieve this via [Shap Values](https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) using something along the following (but using `LinearExplainer` instead of `TreeExplainer`):

````py
# Instantiate model and encoder outside of pipeline for 
# use with shap
model = RandomForestClassifier( random_state=25)
# Fit on train, score on val
model.fit(X_train_encoded, y_train2)
y_pred_shap = model.predict(X_val_encoded)
# Get an individual observation to explain.
row = X_test_encoded.iloc[[-3]]
# Why did the model predict this?
# Look at a Shapley Values Force Plot
import shap
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(row)
shap.initjs()
shap.force_plot(
    base_value=explainer.expected_value[1],
    shap_values=shap_values[1],
    features=row
)```
````

Comment: SHAP values have nothing to do with model coefficients. And this does not provide an answer to the question.

Comment: "SHAP measures the impact of variables taking into account the interaction with other variables.

Shapley values calculate the importance of a feature by comparing what a model predicts with and without the feature. However, since the order in which a model sees features can affect its predictions, this is done in every possible order, so that the features are fairly compared."

This does actually get at what I'm looking for - I used `coefficients` as a term because that's what I previously worked with, but ultimately I want to understand the impact of various inputs on the predictions

Comment: I know what SHAP values are, and I repeat: this is not what has been asked.

Comment: I'll also repeat: I expressed confusion in the wording of my original question. What I was trying to ask for was an insight into how different input values for individual observations impacted their individual predictions. I'd love to hear instruction on how to accomplish this as opposed to simply being told the way I'm trying to achieve it is incorrect, as this does not help me solve the problem.

Are you saying Shap values will not tell me how different input values for individual observations impacted their individual predictions?